# Is it possible to determine or estimate the period for Blum-Micali PRG?

Tags: discrete-logarithm, pseudo-random-generator, random-number-generator

The Blum-Micali is a cryptographically secure pseudorandom number generator.

The construction (from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blum%E2%80%93Micali_algorithm)):

- Let $p$ be an odd prime, and let $g$ be a primitive root modulo $p$.
- Let $x_0$ be a seed, and let $x_{i+1} = g^{x_i}\ \bmod{\ p}$.
- The $i$-th output of the algorithm is 1 if 
  $x_i < \frac{p-1}{2}$. Otherwise the output is 0.

I have toyed with small values of $p$ and have noticed that cycles occur if there's a fixed point, that is $x_{i+1} = x_i = g^{x_i}$.

For example when $g=3$ and $p=7$ (from [wikipedia primitive root example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n#Elementary_example)), there are two fixed points where $3^4 = 4 \bmod 7$ and $3^5 = 5 \bmod 7$. This would be problematic for Blum-Micali generator since it would cycle and repeatedly output the same bit.

Is there a relationship with the size of $p$ and the period which is based on the likelihood of a fixed point?

Comment: Interesting question. The heuristic argument is obvious but I'd be interested in seeing some real (i.e. non-generic) analysis of the properties of $x \mapsto g^x \mod{p}$. Searching for "discrete logarithm fixed point" I found some references, but they all seem to focus on describing the set of primes and primitive roots with at least one fixed point, rather than a lower bound on the number of fixed points for any given $p$.

Comment: The premise seems faulty.  Cycles can occur even if there is no fixed point.  So, focusing on fixed points seems mis-placed, if you really care about cycles.  But, as I explain in my answer, worrying about short cycles is also mis-placed concern.

Comment: Just a note on your statement that fixed points would be a problem for Blum-Micali generator. It will not be a problem, because $g$ is a generator and all $x_i$ < $p$, which means for all $x_i$, $x_{i+1}$ will be a unique integer between $1$ and $p-1$ inclusive. In other words, if the random seed $x_0$ is not a fixed point, which can easily be checked, then subsequent $x_i$ will never reach a fixed point, because you cannot have more than one exponent giving the same remainder.

Comment: Good question! I also want to know the answer to this question. There seems to be no algorithm for calculating the period of the generator per set of parameters

Answer (score 1):

Under the question's hypothesis, $x\mapsto g^x\bmod p$ is a permutation of $\mathbb Z_p^*$, that has some characteristics of being random.

If we take a random permutation of a set of size $s$, the length of the cycle iterating that permutation from a random point has length $l$ with probability exactly $1/s$, independent of integer $l$ with $1\le l\le s$. It follows that the cycle has length $l$ or less with probability exactly $l/s$.

This forms an heuristic argument (obvious, as pointed by Thomas in [comment](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/15429/555#comment32355_15429)) that perhaps it is $\epsilon$-rare that the cycle length of the question's generator is much less than $\epsilon\,p$.

This is however very far from a proof or even a convincing argument. In particular, because $x\mapsto g^x\bmod p$ belongs to a very small and special subset of the permutations of $\mathbb Z_p^*$, with that subset having $(p-1)/2$ elements out of $(p-1)!$ permutations.

By contrast, D.W.'s [argument](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/15433/555) is a valid proof that the cycle length is too large to be found when $p$ is such that the discrete logarithm problem is hard. However that gives a considerably looser safe estimate of the cycle length; perhaps likely at least $2^{100}$ for $2048$-bit randomly-seeded $p$, when the above heuristic argument suggests likely at least $2^{2040}$.

Answer (score 0):

Since Blum-Micali is cryptographically secure, you know that there won't be a short cycle (not one short enough to detect in polynomial time), because a short cycle would violate cryptographic security.  Therefore, you don't need to worry about this.  It's not worth your time worrying about it: it's very unlikely you'll run into a short cycle.

That said, why do you want to use Blum-Micali?  I wouldn't recommend it for any practical application.  Instead, I'd recommend something like AES-CTR.

Comment: Regarding the last sentence, how exactly did you arrive at the conclusion that the OP wanted to use Blum-Micali? Seems to me he was only curious about the implications of fixed points in the permutation function.

Answer (score -3):

What is often recommended is to make sure that your value of g is a "generator" mod p. I don't know if this term is often used, but I've had it defined as cycling through the entirety of a set {0, 1, ..., p - 1} by raising it to consecutive powers mod p. If you use a number with this property, you will never have any short cycles and will in fact generate every value available mod p.

Comment: This doesn't really seem to answer the question.

Comment: $g$ is a generator if and only if $x\mapsto g^x\bmod p$ is a permutation. But permutations can have short cycles, hence it does not follows from $g$ being a generator that the construction in the question has maximum cycle; and experiment (as pointed by the question) shows otherwise. Further, the problem statement has _"let $g$ be a primitive root modulo $p$"_, which means $g$ is a generator, thus this answer's recommendation is already part of the problem statement.